# my jquery tabs are not working after load

Tags: jquery, tabs, load, jquery-ui-tabs

My default jquery tabs are not working after load, what can i do?

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#a').tabs();

var section = $("#header a");
section.on('click', function() {
    $('#load').load(this.id + ' #load');
    window.history.pushState(this.id, this.id, this.id);

    if (this.id == '/p/sign-out') {
        window.location.assign("/p");   
    }
});
```

Comment: Are `#tabs` and `#a` in the elements that are loaded dynamically? You have to initialize the plugin after they're loaded.

Comment: Also, `$('#load').load(this.id + ' #load');` will create a duplicate ID `load`. `.load()` doesn't replace the DIV with the loaded HTML, it puts the HTML inside the DIV.

Comment: what can i do for it, it is not loading dynamicly.... how can i initialize?

Comment: If it's not loading dynamically then `.tabs()` should work. Is the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var section = $("#header a");
section.click(function(){
    $('#load').load(this.id + ' #load', function() {
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    }); 
    window.history.pushState(this.id, this.id, this.id);
    if (this.id == '/p/sign-out') {
        window.location.assign("/p/sign-out");
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't just post a bunch of code. Explain what was wrong in the question, and how the answer fixes it.

Comment: It looks like all you changed was the URL that you use in `window.location.assign()`. What does that have to do with tabs?

Comment: In the question "$('#load').load(this.id + ' #load');" is not a includable function. In the answer now, it is includable and  "$('.tabs').tabs();" tabs function is in it...

Comment: Put the explanation in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: "window.location.assign("/p/sign-out");" is my own code which work with load function. I did not use it for tabs...